# Angular performance, total blocking time

Tags: angular, lighthouse, checkly

In my Angular 16 application I am checking the performance via Checkly tool and via Chrome Lighthouse.

The TTL - Total blocking time score - is totally different: 287 ms in Checkly and just 60 ms in Lighthouse. Why this difference? And, how can I improve that value in an Angular application?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of strategies: lazy loading, standalone components, directives, pure pipes, change detection on push, avoid function calls into template, using (in a proper way ) observables, subscribing to observable in .ts only when needed (if so, don't forget takeUntil destroy!)...

With v17 you will be able to handle fine grained change detection using signal based components.

These were only things came to my mind.

Hope to help you!